# IC2 SLAVE NOT RESPONDING XC8

Tags: i2c, mplab, xc8, mpu6050

Hey guys i've been working on this like 72 hours straight and i can't find the error, i'm working on a PIC16F1719 i'm trying to set 3 peripherials an ADC a I2C Protocol and a USART for comunicating to a BT however the ADC was easy, but i'm having a rough time with the I2C despite the fact i've check the code several times, for some reason when i get the ACK's everything seems OK, but when i go for a lecture on the sensor (MPU6050) nothing shows up but the value i putted last time on the buffer, any ideas why this is happening? It's like the buffer doesn't clear itself and i think i can´t clear it through software, thanks.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming, or is it a hardware question?

Comment: Well i think it goes for both same time, i got my hardware good set, i got the pull up resistors and everything, the main deal is about why the Buffer doesn´t shows the value from the sensor but the address i gave it, like everything got stacked there in the buffer so nothing really happens

Answer (score 0):

i2c slave has the ability to lock the bus if the master does not communicate correctly with it (several possible scenarios...)
This is electirically possible since the 2 wires are wired-and, that means if any slave pulls the clock (for example) down, and keeps it that way, the bus is locked.

- Always check first the values on both wires (using scope or dvm), if '0' it means bus locked.
- Next test the status register of your i2c controller, it may show arbitration error or something of that sort.
- If any of the errors, read the i2c slave part datasheet carefully to check what types of protocol read/write it expects and fix your code.